# Creating a Python Script

Tags: pyqgis, references

Is there any information out there on how to start creating scripts using Python and QGIS 2.10? I only have a little coding experience and an very unsure of how to start.

My first script would probably be something like a process for creating a buffer from a point, setting the properties of the buffer too if possible (e.g. orange, 0.8 line). I do simple tasks in QGIS often and I think scripts would help me a lot.